# What does this mean: 3i2ndDfv2rTHiSisAbouNdArYfORhtTPEefj3q2f

Tags: http

I found this string several times on the Internet, and I wonder what it means, and where it comes from:

```
3i2ndDfv2rTHiSisAbouNdArYfORhtTPEefj3q2f
```

It's often used after a boundery-definition in the `HTTP-Content-Type-Header`:

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--3i2ndDfv2rTHiSisAbouNdArYfORhtTPEefj3q2f
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html

rfc1341 7.2 The Multipart Content-Type

> The body must then contain one or more "body parts," each preceded by an encapsulation boundary, and the last one followed by a closing boundary.

Comment: Where exactly is `3i2ndDfv2rTHiSisAbouNdArYfORhtTPEefj3q2f` in the link you provided?!